# if else with checkbox and string

Tags: c#, windows, compact-framework, .net-2.0, windows-mobile-6.1

could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried so many ways and can't get it to work in all cases at same time.

Our symbol devices have multiple firmware versions that cause issues with the wireless card in the device. if the firmware version is 86.09.0000 it will work fine. If the firmware version if anything else "01.09.000" it will cause issues so i have it dump a cab file with factory firmware and reboot device.

Thanks for help, below is working code.

```
if (checkBox1.Checked && myString == "86.09.0000")
        {

         //check box checked and correct string


        }
        else if ((checkBox1.Checked == false) && (myString == "86.09.0000"))
        {
         //check box not checked and correct string

        }
        else
            {
               // string doesn't match
            }
```

Comment: Where is the problem? any exceptions?

Comment: my message box doesn't work when firmware is wrong. But I should mention checkbox1 is checked.

Comment: What is the problem? What are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Comment: have you tried with (!this.IsChecked(checkBox1))???

Comment: What is the correct firmware? "86.09.0000"? Due to your if, the code inside is only executed if this is the firmware. And the only MessageBox is within this if-statement. What does "wrong firmware" mean? What could be a wrong firmware?

Comment: My program has a checkbox that allows user to WIPE device. I need it to take it to wipe if the box is checked and if not checked it should start the thread. If it has the wrong firmware on device it should update firmware which is where i have install firmware.

Comment: Mythread installs a list of cab files to the device.

Comment: I did try (!this.IsChecked(checkBox1)) at some point but read that ! would not work.

Comment: This question... wtf. "What's wrong?" with no problem description and some code isn't a question. You left out pretty much every important element that involves an answerable question

Comment: 86.09.0000 is the correct firmware
01.09.000 would be bad firmware version that does not work with wireless card in device. But didn't want to be specific in case other versions that don't work correctly exist.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume you mean if myString isn't 86.09.0000... Is your final else in the wrong 'if' statement?

```
        if (checkBox1.Checked && myString == "86.09.0000")
        {

            wipefiles();

        }
        else if ((checkBox1.Checked == false) && (myString == "86.09.0000"))
        {
            if (myThread == null)
            {
                label4.Visible = false;
                pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
                SystemIdleTimerReset();
                menuItem1.Enabled = false;
                myThread = new Thread(MyWorkerThread);
                myThread.IsBackground = true;
                myThread.Start();
            }

        }
        else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Install firmware");
            }
```

Is this possibly what you were trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String oemVersion = oemver.getOEMVersion();
    String myVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

    if (myVersion.Equals(oemVersion))
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            wipefiles();
        else
        {
            if (myThread == null)
            {
                label4.Visible = false;
                pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
                SystemIdleTimerReset();
                menuItem1.Enabled = false;
                myThread = new Thread(MyWorkerThread);
                myThread.IsBackground = true;
                myThread.Start();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Install firmware");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply  add another `"OR" ||` condition in your if statement .See below

```
if (checkBox1.Checked && (myString == "86.09.0000"***||myString="01.09.000"***))
        {

            wipefiles();

        }
        else if ((checkBox1.Checked == false) && (myString == "86.09.0000"***||myString="01.09.000"***))
        {
            if (myThread == null)
            {
                label4.Visible = false;
                pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
                SystemIdleTimerReset();
                menuItem1.Enabled = false;
                myThread = new Thread(MyWorkerThread);
                myThread.IsBackground = true;
                myThread.Start();
            }

        }
        else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Install firmware");
            }
```

Now It's working for you ! But it's not good  .Because it's maay be going to lot of "`OR`" condition . So Please assign the mystring value from when code running!

Comment: You wouldn't want to do this because he's saying that 01.09.000 is incorrect firmware and therefore you would not want it to flag that half of the statement as true.